# I'm not getting all the points on MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE

Tags: android, csv

How to get the all points? I want to store all those points in `csv` file format. One more thing, I have normalized points still not getting all those points!

`DrawingView`-class:

```
public class DrawingView extends View {
    static Path drawPath;
    private Paint drawPaint, canvasPaint;
    static int paintColor = Color.BLACK;
    private float STROKE_WIDTH = 10f;
    private Canvas drawCanvas;
    private Bitmap canvasBitmap;
    private boolean erase = false;
    Context context;
    FileWriter fw;
    private static int mX;
    private static int mY;
    private static ArrayList<Integer> xPoints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private static ArrayList<Integer> yPoints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Integer xInt[]={};
    Integer yInt[]={};
    int x[];
    int y[];

    public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setupDrawing();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
    }

    private void setupDrawing() {
        drawPath = new Path();
        drawPaint = new Paint();
        drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
        drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
        drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        canvasPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);

    }

    private void touch_start(int x, int y) {
        drawPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    private void touch_move(int x, int y) throws IOException {

        drawPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
        arrayPopulate(x, y);

    }

    private void touch_up(int x, int y) {
        drawPath.lineTo(x, y);
        drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
        drawPath.reset();
    }

    public void csvHeader(String s1, String s2) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String line = String.format("%s,%s\n", s1, s2);
        fw.write(line);
    }

    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
    private void csvData(int x, int y) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String line = String.format("%d,%d\n", x, y);
        fw.write(line);
    }

    private void arrayPopulate(int xCord, int yCord) {

        xPoints.add(xCord / 10);
        yPoints.add(yCord / 10);

        xInt=xPoints.toArray(xInt);
        yInt=yPoints.toArray(yInt);

    }


    public void makeFile(Integer[] xArr,Integer yArr[]) {
        x=RemoveDuplicate.removed(xArr);
        y=RemoveDuplicate.removed(yArr);

        try {
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    "Notes");
            if (!f.exists()) {
                f.mkdirs();
            }
            File file = new File(f, "test.txt");
            fw = new FileWriter(file);
            csvHeader("X", "Y");
            for (int i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
                 int xvalue=x[i];
                 int yvalue=y[i];
                csvData(xvalue, yvalue);
                fw.flush(); 
            }
            fw.close();

        } catch (IOException e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {

        canvasPaint.setColor(paintColor);
        int x = (int) e.getX();
        int y = (int) e.getY();

        switch (e.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);
            arrayPopulate(x, y);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            try {
                touch_move(x, y);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch_up(x, y);
            makeFile(xInt, yInt);
            break;

        default:

            return false;
        }

        invalidate();
        return true;

    }

    public void setErase(boolean isErase) throws IOException 
    {
        erase = isErase;
        drawPaint = new Paint();
        if (erase) {

            setupDrawing();
            canvasBitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            fw.close();

        } else {

            setupDrawing();
        }

    }

}
```

`RemoveDuplicate`-class:

```
public class RemoveDuplicate {
    public static int[] removed(Integer[] points)
    {
        int[] input = new int[points.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
            input[i]=points[i].intValue();
        }

        int current = input[0];
        boolean found = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            if (current == input[i] && !found) {
                found = true;
            } else if (current != input[i]) {
                current = input[i];
                found = false;
            } 
        }
        return input ;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean?  If you mean you're missing points in a single finger's touch, remember that touches are batched-  use getHistoricalX and getHistoricalY to get the batched data.  If you mean you're missing fingers, use getX(int pointerid) and getY(pointerid) to get those points.

Comment: I touch only with single figure. Though i'm not getting all those touched points. And i've already used getX and getY  method you can see.

Comment: Those getX and getY are for multiple fingers at the same time.  If you're missing points along a path, its due to batching and you need to use getHistoricalX and getHistoricalY, walking the entire history each event.

Comment: Yeah! I got all those points just by using getHistoricalX and getHistoricalY method after ACTION_UP event! Thank you thank you so much.